# Issue with Console Access to Switch Using Socat: Command Echoing

Tags: linux, networking, console, telnet, netcat

I'm attempting to connect to a switch through the console using the following `socat` command:

```bash
socat tcp4-listen:5050,reuseaddr,fork file:/dev/ttyUSB1,nonblock,raw,echo=0
```

However, when connecting to it from an external source using `Telnet`, I encounter the following problem:

```
Trying 192.168.50.10...
Connected to 192.168.50.10.
Escape character is '^]'.

SW1# 
SW1# ss
ss
% Command incomplete: ss
SW1# 
SW1#
```

The command prompt echoes, and the commands are printed twice. Even the commands I send are echoed back.

When I connect with `nc`, I encounter the following issue:

```
SW1# sss
sss
% Unknown command: sss
SW1#
```

It re-echos the entered command.

I would appreciate guidance on how to resolve this issue.

i use `echo=0` to solve this but it didn't work.

Comment: Same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77386866/how-to-resolve-double-echo-issue-in-telnet-connection-using-socat-with-raw-echo)? Are you in the same class?

Comment: yep, He is my colleague

Comment: Did you check what's "behind" /dev/ttyUSB1? Maybe there is another computer with a tty connected and the echo is produced there?

Comment: No, behind `ttyUSB1` is a layer 3 switch, and I think a newline character is inserted in `telnet`, but this is not the problem in `nc`. But I don't know the reason for echoing the order itself

Comment: Still, it might be possible that the switch echoes the input. This is ok when the local terminal (probably a console window) is set to raw mode. Thus you may try the following client command:  socat -,cfmakeraw TCP:192.168.50.10:5050

Comment: Thank you. With your guide, the connection was established fine, but unfortunately our client was using `pyats` in python and I could not use a different client. However, I was able to solve this problem by changing the server to the `ser2net` tool. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

After extensive research, I found an alternative tool for `socat` called `ser2net`. I implemented a server console by adding the following configuration in the `/etc/ser2net.conf` file:

```bash
2204:telnet:0:/dev/ttyUSB0:9600 8DATABITS NONE 1STOPBIT
```

This configuration allows you to access the console of your server over Telnet on port 2204 with the specified serial port settings.